# Setear valores maximos y minimos de una lectura analogica en arduino

Tags: c++, arduino

Mi programa es el siguiente:

Leo un valor analogo de un pin de arduino para luego mostrar dicho valor en una lcd, y luego con el monitor serial establesco valores maximos y minimos con los siguientes comandos:

vma: numero para valor maximo(ejemplo vma:4000)
vmi: numero para valor minimo(ejemplo vmi:1000)

luego de setear un valor maximo, si la lectura analogica es un valor  mayor o igual al valor ingresado, una señal se activa.
Si seteo un valor minimo, y la lectura analogica es un valor menor o igual al valor ingresado, otra salida se activa.
Haora, no es necesario ingresar ambos valores maximo y minimo para que el programa funcione, si solo se ingresa un valor, el programa trabajara solo con ese valor.

El problema que tengo es es cuanto a validaciones.
Si el programa setea un valor minimo(ejemplo 2000) y luego se setea un valor maximo(1000), este al ser un valor menor que pertenece a valores minimos no deberia de setearse, y simplemente mantenerse en cero si es la primera vez que se setea un valor maximo, si ya habia un valor valido existente, el programa deberia de conservar el valor anterior hasta ingresar un valor valido, y viceversa cuando el caso es al revez.
¿Como puedo logar esto?

Unicamente logre validar si valor maximo y minimo son iguales, no se setee el ultimo valor igual.

Gracias de antemano.
codigo:

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
LiquidCrystal lcd(D0, D1, D2, D3, D4, D5);
int analogoPin=A8;
float val=0;
float val1=0;
int ventilador=D6;
int calefactor=D7;
String tecla= " ";
String texto= " ";
String num=" ";
String compmi="";
String compma="";
int numi=1;
int numa=0;
int num2=0;

void setup() {
  pinMode(calefactor, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ventilador, OUTPUT);
 lcd.begin(16,2);
 Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop() {
val=analogRead(analogoPin);
if (Serial.available() > 0) {
  texto="";
  num="";
 tecla = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');
 char vt[tecla.length()+1];
 tecla.toCharArray(vt, tecla.length()+1);
 for(int i=0; i<tecla.length()+1;i++)
 {
   vt[i]= tolower(vt[i]);
 }


for(int i=0; i<tecla.length()+1;i++)
 {
   if(isalpha(vt[i]))
   {
      texto= texto+ vt[i];

   }
   if(isdigit(vt[i]))
   {
      num= num+ vt[i];
   }

 }

}

 texto.trim();
 num.trim();
 Serial.println(num);



if(texto=="vmi")
{
   if(num.toInt()!=numa)
  {
  
  compmi=texto;
 
    numi=num.toInt();
  }
}

if(texto=="vma")
{
  if(num.toInt()!=numi)
  {
  compma=texto;
  
    numa=num.toInt();
  }

}




if(compmi=="vmi")
{
if(numi<=4095 && numi>=0)
{
if(val<=numi)
{
  digitalWrite(calefactor,1);
  Serial.print("Valor minimo seteado a: ");

}
else
{
  digitalWrite(calefactor,0);

}

}
}

if(compma=="vma")
{
if(numa<=4095 && numa>=0)
{
if(val>=numa)
{
  digitalWrite(ventilador,1);
  Serial.print("Valor maximo seteado a: ");

}
else
{
  digitalWrite(ventilador,0);

}

}
}






lcd.clear();
lcd.print(val,0);
lcd.setCursor(0,1);
val1=(val*3.3/2703);
lcd.print(val1,3);
delay(1000);
delay(1000);

 

}
```

Comment: Pensaste en algo como: if (minimoNuevo < máximo) mínimo = minimoNuevo ?

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas implementar una lógica para manejar las condiciones y comparaciones adecuadas cuando se ingresan valores máximos y mínimos. Puedes agregar algunas variables booleanas para indicar si se ha establecido un valor máximo o mínimo y ajustar tu lógica en consecuencia. Aquí hay una versión modificada de tu código:

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

LiquidCrystal lcd(D0, D1, D2, D3, D4, D5);
int analogoPin = A8;
float val = 0;
float val1 = 0;
int ventilador = D6;
int calefactor = D7;
String tecla = " ";
String texto = " ";
String num = " ";
String compmi = "";
String compma = "";
int numi = 1;
int numa = 0;
bool vmi_set = false;
bool vma_set = false;

void setup() {
  pinMode(calefactor, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ventilador, OUTPUT);
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  val = analogRead(analogoPin);
  
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    texto = "";
    num = "";
    tecla = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');
    char vt[tecla.length() + 1];
    tecla.toCharArray(vt, tecla.length() + 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < tecla.length() + 1; i++) {
      vt[i] = tolower(vt[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < tecla.length() + 1; i++) {
      if (isalpha(vt[i])) {
        texto = texto + vt[i];
      }
      if (isdigit(vt[i])) {
        num = num + vt[i];
      }
    }
  }

  texto.trim();
  num.trim();
  Serial.println(num);

  if (texto == "vmi") {
    if (num.toInt() != numa) {
      compmi = texto;
      numi = num.toInt();
      vmi_set = true;
    }
  }

  if (texto == "vma") {
    if (num.toInt() != numi) {
      compma = texto;
      numa = num.toInt();
      vma_set = true;
    }
  }

  if (vmi_set && compmi == "vmi") {
    if (numi <= 4095 && numi >= 0) {
      if (val <= numi) {
        digitalWrite(calefactor, 1);
        Serial.print("Valor minimo seteado a: ");
      } else {
        digitalWrite(calefactor, 0);
      }
    }
    vmi_set = false;
  }

  if (vma_set && compma == "vma") {
    if (numa <= 4095 && numa >= 0) {
      if (val >= numa) {
        digitalWrite(ventilador, 1);
        Serial.print("Valor maximo seteado a: ");
      } else {
        digitalWrite(ventilador, 0);
      }
    }
    vma_set = false;
  }

  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print(val, 0);
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  val1 = (val * 3.3 / 2703);
  lcd.print(val1, 3);
  delay(1000);
}
```